# Unsupervised Learning with Time Series data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, statistics, machine-learning-model, unsupervised-learning

I'm working with data which has daily aggregated user actvity over the course of several months (a user doesn't have to make an activity every day). I'm looking for a way to cluster similar users together but I'm a bit confused how to incorporate time series data into unsupervised learning algorithms.

My thoughts on approaching this is to pivot the data so that there is are columns for each day of the months. However, I feel that this would lead to the "curse of dimensionality" and so I was wondering if there was a better approach.